# Using a MySql sub to connect to database - failing to connect to any host

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm working on a wrapper for the MySql .NET connector class. Thus far it has worked correctly and without flaw. However, I must have changed something because it will not connect to my MySql server at all, and I can access the server via phpMyAdmin.

So now, I have the following code:

```vb
Public Function Connect(ByVal Host As String,
                        ByVal Database As String,
                        ByVal Username As String,
                        ByVal Password As String) As Boolean
    Try
        _ConnInfo.Host = Host
        _ConnInfo.Username = Username
        _ConnInfo.Password = Password
        _ConnInfo.Database = Database
        _ConnInfo.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0}; user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false",
                                                   _ConnInfo.Host,
                                                   _ConnInfo.Username,
                                                   _ConnInfo.Password,
                                                   _ConnInfo.Database)
        _mysqlConn.ConnectionString = _ConnInfo.ConnectionString
        _mysqlConn.Open()
        CreateEventArgs(eArgs, currentID, False, "Open Connection", _ConnInfo, Me, MySQL_Wrapper_Operation.Connect, Nothing)
        RaiseEvent OperationCompleted(eArgs)
        OnConnect()
        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        OnConnectError(ex)
        CreateEventArgs(eArgs, currentID, True, "Open Connection", _ConnInfo, Me, MySQL_Wrapper_Operation.Connect, Nothing, ex)
        RaiseEvent OperationCompleted(eArgs)
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

`_ConnInfo` is an instance of a class for storing my MySql connection information:

```vb
Public Class MySQL_Wrapper_ConnectionInfo
    Public Sub New()

    End Sub
    Public Sub New(ByVal _Host As String,
                   ByVal _Database As String,
                   ByVal _Username As String,
                   ByVal _Password As String,
                   Optional ByVal _ConnectionString As String = "")
        Host = _Host
        Database = _Database
        Username = _Username
        Password = _Password
        ConnectionString = _ConnectionString
    End Sub
    Public Host As String
    Public Database As String
    Public Username As String
    Public Password As String
    Public ConnectionString As String
End Class
```

Anyway, when I call `Connect("10.131.120.46", "studenttest", "studenttest", "********")`, my function returns false and the error I get is:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

I've tried using another connection string as from [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/):

```vb
    _ConnInfo.ConnectionString = $"Server={_ConnInfo.Host};Database={_ConnInfo.Database};Uid={_ConnInfo.Username};Pwd={_ConnInfo.Password};Pooling=False;"
```

The above gives me the same result. At runtime, I am able to find the connection string, which is this:

> server=10.131.120.46; user id=studenttest; password=********; database=studenttest; pooling=false

I'd just like to note the error occurs at `_mysqlConn.Open()` (where `_mysqlConn` is declared `Private Property _mysqlConn As New MySqlConnection` in the class).

I'd be much appreciative if someone could give me a head's up where I'm making a mistake.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if I told you...the MySQL Provider includes a MySQLHelper?

Comment: Then I would probably cry myself to sleep, but besides the point. I'm trying to make this as a learning task for myself - and a way for me to easily be able to utilise the MySql class because I wrote everything myself (the wrapper) :)